# Rounding Error in Python

Tags: python, excel, floating-point, precision, vba

I want to round a figure in python to 2 decimal places using the following code:

```
a = 3260
b = 0.000075
c =  a * b # // (0.24449999999999997)
result = round(a * b, 2)
```

but the result I get is: 0.23999999999999999

I'm comparing this to excel VBA where the `result` is `0.24`

I can't figure out why (a) the number isn't truncated and (b) why its different to the VBA equivalent:

```
WorksheetFunction.MRound(c, 0.01)
```

Any tips appreciated!

EDIT: I'm using python tools for VS2010 and python 2.6.

Comment: `round(3260 * 0.000075, 2)` returns `.24` for me. http://ideone.com/VFQ9Ag

Comment: In the IDLE interpreter it does the same for me but this behavior is not carried through to the script I'm running.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and python specific: [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error)

Comment: Please do the minimum of searching before you ask a question, this gets asked every few days. First result for `google(python floating point)`: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Thanks for the responses. In fact, I have spent quite a while searching for a solution or explanation but was not able to determine which representation of the floating point (py or vba) was correct, hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value 0.24 can not be exactly represented as an IEEE binary floating point number.  That's why you obtain 0.23999999999999999 .  I'm not 100% sure if VBA uses the same format.  If it did, it could be "realizing" that 0.23999999999999999 is too close to 0.24 and displaying the later.  But only when *displaying* it.  Internally the inexact number would still be stored, as the exact value 0.24 **does not exist** in this IEEE format.

You could force a behaviour similar to VBA's by displaying results with 2 decimals.  Formatting routines do a better job in this sense because they round to string representations, which certainly support "2.40" (as a string, not a number).

```
print( "%.2f" % 0.23999999999999999 )
```

Another solution is to use a decimal floating or fixed point arithmetic package able to represent decimal numbers with perfect precision (but not binary ones).  Python's standard package `decimal` does an extremely good job and supports both.

A third solution is, in certain way, to implement such a package in a simple and personal, but very labor-intensive way.  Assuming that all your numbers need to be stored with 2 decimals, you can scale them by 100 and store them as integers.  Example:

```
a =  1326048  # /100=  13260.48 ; s=2
b =   234493  # /100=   2344.93 ; s=2
c = 34756334  # /100= 347563.34 ; s=2
# All three numbers are in the same scale, so they can be added directly.  Scale of the result is the same as the numbers (s=2)
d = a + b + c  # /100; s=2
# In multiplication, scale of the result is the sum of the scale of the factors. 
# This has the advantage that the scale of operands can be different.
e = a * b  # /10000; s=4
# But we want to go back to 2 decimals quickly.  So, round to 2 decimals.  And yes, division subtracts scales.
e = ( e + 50 ) // 100  # /100 s=2
```

I would **not** recommend this (or the next "solution") at all.  They are here just to minimally explain how this kind of packages work.

You can also keep track of scale in a separate variable and compute the necessary scale adjustments during runtime, but this is **completely** equivalent to build one of the mentioned packages by yourself.  In your particular case,

```
a_m= 326
a_s= -1   # a= a_m / 10**a_s = 326 / 10**-1 = 3260
b_m= 75
b_s= 6    # b= b_m / 10**b_s = 75 / 10**6 = 0.000075
c_m= a_m * b_m  # =24450
c_s= a_s + b_s  # = -1 + 6 = 5  ;  c= c_m / 10**c_s = 24450 / 10**5 = 0.24450
# Round to 2 decimals
r= 2
d_m= ( c_m + 10**(c_s-r)//2 ) // 10**(c_s-r)
# d_m = ( 24450 + 10**(5-2)//2 ) // 10**(5-2) = ( 24450 + 500 ) // 1000 = 24
d_s= r  # = 2  ;  d= dm / 10**ds = 24 / 10**2 24 / 100 = 0.24
```

At this point, you want to output an "unscaled" version of `c`.  Two alternatives are:

```
print( ("%d.%0"+str(c_s)+"d") % ( c // 100 , c % 100 ) )  # Which is the same as...
print( ("%d.%02d") % ( c // 100 , c % 100 ) )  # The case c_s < 0 requires a different expression
```

or going the floating point way

```
print( "%.2f" % c / 100 )
```